# Thermal Boundary Layer

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, convection

When we study convection in Heat Transfer then there a part where a fluid flows over a plate maintained at a temperature T. In this case heat transfer ocurrs both by conduction as well as convection and a thermal boundary layer develops.

I want to know how does the depth of this thermal boundary layer keeps on increasing as we move forward in the plate?

Comment: The thermal boundary layer gets thicker with distance along the plate for the same reason that, in transient heating or cooling of a semi-infinite slab, the thermal boundary layer gets thicker with time.

Comment: excellent approximate equations exist to solve this class of problem, see the engineering SE. -NN